# Best Index Combinations, given NDV (number of distinct values)

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a READ-ONLY Oracle table with 2 million rows.

The NDV ( number of distinct values for each col is as follows )

```
C1 : 2
C2 : 40000
C3 : 40
C4 : 10000
C5 : 10000
C6 : 2
```

Assume a query does a search on all of the above columns.

What would be the best composite index combinations given the above ?

Also - ignore the fact that DML will slow down due to more indexes, because the database is always in READ_ONLY mode.

Comment: If you are searching on all the columns, then you want to include all the columns in the index.  The ordering of the columns will have little impact on performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - If the first column is say C2 ( which has NDV=40,000 ), won't the query go to highly selective part of B-tree ? On the other hand, if C1 is first column of an index - it will still have to sort through 40,000 values

Comment: . . "go to" is a strange way of describing what happens.  All six keys are compared at the root, perhaps with short-cutting if not all six are needed.  This is then repeated at the subsequent nodes.  The shortcutting might benefit from having higher cardinality keys first.  But that is also affected by data types, the length of keys, and the rules for comparison, so there are other considerations.  And I would consider that a micro-optimization for queries that use all six keys.

Comment: What operators does the query use in the where clause, =, <>, like, >, < ? What logical operators are used: AND, OR, some combination of them  ? Does the query retrieve solely columns C1-C6 in the select clause, or other columns than C1..6 too ? Does the query use any GROUP BY, max(), min(), sum() aggregate functions, analytic functions?  It would be best if you show the whole query in the question, The best answer as usual is - it depends.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to order the columns of a multi-column index is to look at all the queries against a particular table and place those columns referenced most often in WHERE clauses toward the front of the column list. -- Index compression is another consideration: placing C1, C6, and C3 in front may provide a smaller index. -- But otherwise yes I would probably place C2, C4, and C5 up front, if other considerations did not come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information which I became aware of - and it should have been included in the problem description.

Turns out that the database is READ-ONLY database. So when we have a table with few columns of very low cardinality, it makes it a very good candidate for BIT-MAPPED index.

I created a bit-mapped index on columns C1, C3, C6 and it really boosted performance.